# Auto Layout: Displaying content relative to container

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, xcode-storyboard

I'm having some issues developing an iPhone application. I have a `UITableView` on a screen and have made a template for how I want to lay things out. I made sure that the constraints are satisfied and when my program compiles, I get no auto layout issues. However, when I run my program on the simulator, some of the text is not shown but I know it should be there. Here is how things look on the `Storyboard`:

[image: How things are laid out on my screen]

However, this is how things look when I run the program on the iPhone simulator, it appears as so:[image: How it appears on simulator]

I am only worried about the `From Date` and `To Date` fields not being displayed because if I move them more to the left, I can eventually see them. Moreover, I made sure to make the `To Date` field's `Trailing Space to Container Margin`by `8 px` so I don't really understand why these two fields aren't showing. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: Image of `To Date` constraints:
[image: Image of To Date Constraints]

Edit 2: Image of how table view cell looks like now:[image]

Comment: Have you tried pinning the to date label to the right side of the table view cell?

Comment: @Douglas I simply selected the `To Date` label and did cntrl + dragged to the right of the screen (labeled Content View) and I selected `Trailing space to Container Margin`

Comment: Perhaps you need to do that as well with the container view. It seems as though the container view is larger than your screen view.

Comment: @Douglas how can I see if my container view is larger than my screen view?

Comment: Check the constraints on the table view itself. See if it is pinned to both sides of the view controller.

Comment: @Douglas it isn't pinned to both sides of the view controller. I will try to fix this. You mention that my container view is larger than my screen view however--is there anyway to fix this? I would like to have my view controller the same size as my screen views so that I can lay things out properly, as opposed to compiling then moving things accordingly, or is that not good practice?

Comment: You can pin the edges of the cell to the sides. You can also set the width of the cell to equal the width of the container. You might be able to see this by changing the orientation of the app in the simulator.

Comment: Sorry, went to bed!  Are you using size classes as well?

Comment: @Douglas yes I am using size classes. Would this affect it in any way?

Comment: Yes, because it might not look right for the iPhone but it all works out if you change constraints for the different size classes. Have you gotten the labels to show?

Comment: @Douglas yes I have gotten the labels to show. I just had to pin the tableview width/height and everything works fine now. Thanks for your help! The other issue I'm just having is that now things are all scrunched up. I want it to look like the first image I posted but the image ends up looking like the last image I made in the original post. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Glad you got it working!  There is really no way around getting the scrunched up look since you have limited space to work with. You can make the fonts smaller if you want. And then for the iPad version, with class sizes you can change the font to a bigger size.

Comment: @Douglas ah okay thanks for your help then! Just one last question: when I look at Apple documentation and such, it says that I should use not smaller than point 11 font but in my application I am already using point 12 font.. would I simply need to keep making things smaller so that they fit better onto the screen in that case? Because clearly I can't increase the width of the screen

Comment: Either do the smaller font, or change the layout a bit. Maybe put the date labels one above the other and increase the font. You can make the cell as big as you want so maybe even put some of the labels under the picture.

Comment: @Douglas great. thank you so much for the suggestions. I appreciate all the help you've given me! If you write an answer, I can accept it as the best answer. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the labels are not showing because of size classes and the difference between the different screen sizes.  In your story board the original view controller is a square shape.  Make sure to pin the labels to the side of the cell that you want them to attach to.  This will make sure they stay where you want them to.  Also make sure that you pin the actual table view to the superview so you can see the labels.  I have always pinned to the top, bottom, and both sides, to accommodate different screen sizes and rotation.  You may need to change the constraints for the other size classes.  This may make some things look they are bunched up a bit with the smaller screen size, but you can always change the font or the format of the cell to fit everything in.

If you want to change a constraint for another size class, just select that size class at the bottom of the story board.  Select the label, and then in the size inspector you can make the constraints you don't want to be unable, and hook up some other constraints to make it work.  Ray Wenderlich's web site has a great tutorial on size classes and adaptive layout.  You can find it [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial).

Happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

Your "missing" labels are probably too far to the right, outside the screen boundaries. This could happen if your view controller is wider in the storyboard than when you run it. Make sure that your labels have constraints for **trailing space** -- that will cause them to always be within the screen bounds no matter the screen width.

Also, use the Debug View Hierarchy in Xcode to see where those labels actually end up.

**UPDATE**:

Try overriding `awakeFromNib` method in your `UITableViewCell` subclass:

```
override func awakeFromNib()
{
    contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight
}
```

Comment: Hi, I do have my labels with constraints for `Trailing Space` which is why this is confusing me. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @user1871869 could you post a screenshot of all the constraints you have for the "To Date" label? That could help shed the light on what's going on.

Comment: It is in the above post! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Your constraints look correct. See my updated answer, let me know if my new suggestion helps.

Comment: Hi, I apologize but I am actually using Swift and not Objective C. Is there any equivalent place where I can put that line?

Comment: @user1871869 it's the same in both Swift and Objective C. As long as you have a `UITableViewCell` subclass, you can override `awareFromNib`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83920/discussion-between-user1871869-and-blackrider).